I wanted to provide an answer for my question but it has been deleted

I have a question about my Server Fault post: Server not finding storage device driver. Can't see hard drives and unable to start Windows Server 2019
I posted this question about a month ago here or Server Fault and I now want to provide an answer to it.
The question was down-voted (in my opinion unfairly) and has now been deleted.
Is it possible to get this question undeleted so that I can provide an answer?

Fairly. This is not a legacy system that you had to support and couldn't've updated, but a new install. What's wrong with this is explained in this answer. You could've been installing Server 2016 and use that for a file server. Or Linux, pretty all modern distros still fully support this hardware and with modern Samba you'll be able to join it to your domain and serve files in a manner that is indistinguishable from the Windows-based file server. You've chosen the most unreasonable way to solve this, and this is why it's genuine off topic here.

@NikitaKipriyanov Just like the person who commented on the question you seem to have completely misunderstood it. The question had NOTHING TO DO WITH THE OPERATING SYSTEM. The question was about getting the server to boot. I simply listed what I had tried as I thought that was the rules of the site. If installing a different OS was the solution then it SHOULD HAVE BEEN WRITTEN AS AN ANSWER.
As it turned out the problem was the driver for the storage controller. Nothing to do with the OS. The server has now been running Server 2019 flawlessly for weeks.

Driver is the part of the OS, as per standard academic definition of the operating system. Driver is required for the OS to abstract and manage hardware, which is one of reasons of having an OS in the first place. The sentence "not the OS problem but the driver" is nonsense.

@NikitaKipriyanov You are still missing the point. The question was not about installing any particular operating system. It wasn’t about a new install. It was about getting a server back up and running again. I would have been quite happy to install a different OS if that was the answer. I don’t see how a question about a specific server fault is off topic on a site called Server Fault.

Your question was automatically deleted because it matches the criteria

the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
has −1 score
has no answers
is not locked
has no active bounty

There is no undeleted option.
You can post a new question and then share your experience and knowledge by posting your own answer. There is even a specific check-box below the question form for that:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/
https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer
